# New monitor doesn't display text the same as old monitor

Tags: display, lcd

I've just purchased a new Samsung Syncmaster PX2370 and it doesn't seem to be displaying text the same way as my old Apple monitor. On the Apple monitor text looks a little stronger and more detailed where on the Samsung monitor text looks weaker and less readable (see below screenshot). Can anyone explain this? Are there any ways to fix it?

[image]

Comment: How did you take the pictures? Are these screenshots or from a camera?

Comment: What @Nitrodist said.  If these are screenshots the difference is in software which means it has nothing to do with the monitor.  If this is in Windows, MAYBE your ClearType settings have something to do with it...

Comment: @Nitodist these are screenshots. Same computer two different monitors

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the screenshot. These screenshots are displaying exactly what I see on the two different monitors.

Comment: There can also be graphics card specific settings that you enabled per monitor to enhance the colors. I know Nvidia has these options (and fairly certain about ATI as well).

Answer (score 1):

Are you driving the Samsung at its native resolution?

LCDs are particularly bad when displaying images at something other than their native resolution.

The Samsung has a resolution of 1920 x 1080. Make sure your graphics card is set to that.

[Source](http://www.digitalversus.com/samsung-syncmaster-px2370-p357_8191_36.html)

Comment: Thanks Chris, yes I have it running at 1920 x 1080 @ 60 Hz

Answer (score 0):

Check your screen resolution, bit depth and color format settings (under advanced).

Their ought to be something in the monitor settings of Windows or your driver Control Panel that causes this.

Comment: Tom... the screen resolution on the Samsung is larger than the Apple

Comment: Still, have you checked the other settings in both places?

Answer (score 0):

If the differences are visible in screenshots captured via software (as apposed to pictures taken of the screen) then they must be rooted in the OS, driver or application, not the hardware of the monitors.  I would begin by seeing if different driver profiles are activated by switching the monitors.